# How does a sentence emphasize the narrator's growing sense of nervousness?

Tags: sentence-meaning, exam-questions

( a question in an ACT English exam) It is impossible to talk—or protest—over the engines’ roar and the noise of the wind that blasts through the open doorways on either side of the narrow fuselage.________But your instructor smiles confidently.She gives you the thumbs-up sign.

Why filling "This is just as well, because if you could protest, you might." in the blank will emphasize the narrator's growing sense of nervousness? But adding "the wind rushing in is loud" will not have this effect?

Is there any implicit meaning of the former option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is impossible to talk—or protest—over the engines’ roar and the noise of the wind that blasts through the open doorways on either side of the narrow fuselage.________But your instructor smiles confidently.She gives you the thumbs-up sign.

You want to put something in the blank that shows the "narrator's" growing sense of nervousness.

First of all, I'm not sure the narrator will be nervous. The narrator is the person speaking the text, and they refer to *your* instructor giving *you* the thumbs-up. Who is "you"? The narrator is the first person, I think it is the second person - the subject - who is nervous. If they were the same person then it would be written as first-person perspective, saying "**my** instructor... gave **me** the thumbs-up"

What you insert in the blank should logically follow what has been said, but also lead into what follows. I would suggest something like:

> "You look at your instructor with trepidation, your nervousness written all over your face."

You suggested, "This is just as well, because if you could protest, you might". That doesn't really say that the person **is** scared - it only says they **might** protest, **if** they could.

Comment: I agree with your analysis of “This is just as well, because if you could protest, you might." not exhibiting nervousness, but it is the right answer, which is why I don't understand

Comment: @crucifyficklecrank When you say "the right answer", I don't see how there can be one correct answer to a 'fill in the blank' question. Was it multiple choice? If so, you should have said.

Comment: It is just as well (that the noise is too loud to hear anyone talking), because the person ('you') is tempted to protest - presumably to say "I don't want to do this."

Comment: @ Astralbee my bad, I should've said it is a multiple choice question

Answer (score 0):

Some people will not mind hearing a loud wind. Therefore this does not necessarily indicate a growing sense of nervousness.

This sounds like parachuting or skydiving. I have done both. I wasn't nervous about the noise or the wind. I was nervous about jumping out of the plane!

Comment: I see, but could u explain why ""This is just as well, because if you could protest, you might."" emphasizes the scare the author has>